# How to make initial call/request within a Progressive Web App (PWA)?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I want to fetch some data from a server when my PWA app is opened/loaded.
From a web perspective, i might have some script that executes when the body is loaded, or something to that effect.

Would this approach be similar or identical within the PWA context?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it so that your PWA redirects to a specific url on start.

`"start_url": "<insert url to api>"`

For reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#start_url